# Can't update table in MySQL, I am using the workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, updating

I am a fairly new user to MySQL although I am fairly experienced with SQL (DB2 environment). I am using the workbench to run queries and update statements.  I am having a problem updating data in a table which I have been able to prior. I'm able to select rows but when I go to update based on the same criteria, the return message is:

```
**0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 9 Changed: 0 Warnings: 0**

Update gina1.proj001_bcbs set contract_percentage = 1.50 

where contract_category = 'All Other Services' 
       and doctor = 'JSmith' ;

When I run the same WHERE clause with a select I get the correct list of records.

**9 row(s) returned**  and I get the correct list of data. 

select * from gina1.proj001_bcbs

where contract_category = 'All Other Services' 
       and doctor = 'JSmith' ;
```

I do not believe I am logging but I can't say for sure, I did ready somewhere about resetting the log.  If someone can help it would be great.

Answer (score 2):

This means simply, that all relevant records already have `contract_percentage = 1.50`

- **0 row(s) affected** : No rows were affected by your query
- **Rows matched: 9** : 9 rows were found, ...
- **Changed: 0** : ... but none of them had to be changed
- **Warnings: 0** : Nothing recoverable bad happened while runinng the query

.

```
Update gina1.proj001_bcbs set contract_percentage = 2.50 
where contract_category = 'All Other Services' and doctor = 'JSmith' ;
```

Is ver likely to bring you **9 row(s) affected Rows matched: 9 Changed: 9 Warnings: 0**

Comment: Eugen, thank you for your response.  I didn't realize that that was how it worked.